# Data Modeling Problem - Schema to store varying number of data points

Tags: database-design

I need a schema to store varying number of data points. There are different data types. Each data type can have varying number of data points. For example: Data Type 1 will have 3 data points, Data Type 2 will have 4 data points, Data Type 3 will have 5 data point, etc. Each one of the data point name should be configurable. I need feedback on the schema I came up with. I need to flatten this data but I couldn't figure out how to do that and also have the data point names configurable.

[image]

Comment: Is [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) what you're looking for? There are [pros and cons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios) so we probably can't decide for you, as your example is very generic as written.

Comment: @LowlyDBA thank you! The links were very useful.